# Por que usar regions no C#?

Tags: c#

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens de se utilizar `#regions` no `C#`?

Seu uso realmente facilita a organização do código?

```
#region

/* Código */

#endregion
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É irrefutável que as *regions* facilitam a organização, mas deve-se tomar certo cuidado com o que realmente você pretende organizar.

Recomendo utilizá-las quando se tem em mente as seguintes finalidades:

- Agrupar código gerado;
- Separar trechos de código grandes;
- Outros fins de legibilidade.

Acredito que o uso de *regions* para separar membros de uma classe de acordo com níveis de proteção (private, public, etc) seja justificável, porém defino seu uso como preferencial pois, enquanto em certas vezes o melhor a se fazer é agrupá-los de acordo com sua funcionalidade, em outras torna-se mais viável organizá-las tendo como base as próprias necessidades de sua aplicação.

Agora, usar *regions* para esconder código "feio" é condenável; quando o intuito é esconder, por que não evitar futuras confusões e gastar uma pequena parte do tempo na refatoração de determinada funcionalidade?

Comment: +1 por condenar regions para esconder partes feias do código. =D Tem gente que faz isso mesmo, hehe!

Comment: +1 pelo mesmo motivo do @MiguelAngelo

Comment: Existe maneira fazer isso no Javascript ?

Answer (score 4):

A ideia dele é diminuir a quantidade de código exibida na tela, agrupando funções comuns. A vantagem é deixar o código mais sucinto para leitura.

A desvantagem é que as *regions* escondem as assinaturas dos métodos. Quando é importante ver as assinaturas de cada método, o atalho <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> É mais útil.

Comment: Eu costumo utilizar #region e ctrl+M e ctrl+O em conjuntos.

Crio por exemplo uma mar de Fields e Properties, daí eu utilizo a #region Fields para isolar minhas fields e #region Properties pra isolar as properties... #region Constructor e por ai vai indo... dai uso Ctrl+M pra deixar todos os métodos reduzidos tbm... com isso eu considero que eu tenho um ganho de organização, pois daí sei claramente onde ir... por exemplo se tenho q mexer em uma property, vou direto ali na region e na property, isso qdo não lembro o nome dela pra usar os atalhos de navegação

Comment: Também uso, mas #region uso menos.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é só uma forma de organizar o código, e geralmente é usado por código gerado.

Em códigos não gerados recomendo um certo cuidado ao usar regions,
pois quando usadas para separar códigos de acordo com uma classificação qualquer,
elas tendem a ficar desatualizadas.

- Por exemplo, se usar regions para agrupar os membros privados, e algum dia algum deles precisar se tornar públic, eu realmente aposto que o membro vai continuar dentro da region.

O uso que eu recomendo, é agrupar membros que possuem alguma ligação real. Por exemplo:

- um campo estático, inicializado apenas uma vez, que serve a um único método, poderia ser colocado dentro de uma region junto com o método... obviamente, sou favorável a uma nomenclatura que também indique que esse campo faz parte desse método, de forma que outros programadores saibam disso